# NGINX modify the request uri

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location, proxypass

this is my first time to post here, I'm hoping you could help me with my problem.

SCENARIO: I want to host multiple website in nginx by using location directive and proxy_pass directive. For example, I have 2 external webserver named www.webserver1.com and www.webserver2.com.

In my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.nginx.proxy;

    location /webserver1 {
    proxy_pass http://www.webserver1.com/;
    }

    location /webserver2 {
    proxy_pass http://www.webserver2.com/;
    }
}
```

My webservers are responding, but the uri in location directive are appended when requesting to the external webservers. For example, when I access via my client browser

> my.nginx.proxy/webserver1

The request is passed to

> http://www.webserver1.com/webserver1

In which case /webserver1 is not existing and thus return HTTP ERROR 404 responded by my webserver. I just want to be redirected to http://www.webserver1.com without the /webserver1 uri but the URL in my client's browser is shown as

> my.nginx.proxy/webserver1

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing it right, but perhaps your version of nginx is < 1.1.12.

> Before version 1.1.12, if proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the
>   original request URI might be passed instead of the changed URI in
>   some cases.

It was only in nginx 1.1.12 and above that they enabled stripping of the location from the request when you specify the url (/) in the proxy_pass parameter.

```
  location /webserver1 {
    # trailing slash at end of url should replace /webserver1 with /
    # if your version of nginx is > 1.1.12
    proxy_pass http://www.webserver1.com/; 
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    # If you want to pass the original host name (my.nginx.proxy) up to 
    # webserver1, you can set the Host header.
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

Try updating nginx.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?#proxy_pass